# Angular Material Data Table contents within row

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

When you have a table using md-data-table, How do you get the data  for a particular row. Basically each row has a menu button and once they click on that button the data in that row should be saved in a variable:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html :

```
 <td md-cell>
    <label>{{item.count}}</label>
    <i ng-click="setSomeVar(item)">you_icon</i>
</td>
```

method in controller :

```
$scope.setSomeVar = function(item)
{
    $scope.someVar = item.count;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The row would be an array of objects using the md-data table with this example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vgNdJb
but instead of a check box there would be a button

Comment: so, there is a icon or button, you can put here whatever you want, it should work